# ctrl + up arrow going nuts in excel 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office

In Excel, if I press `ctrl` + `up`, or `shift` + `ctrl` + `up`, I expect the selection to jump to the top of the sheet. However, as of today, it triggers something that starts, and keeps on, adding charts and macro sheets until I alt-tab out of the program. Does anyone have an idea why, and how to get rid of it?

Some observations:

- There is no problem with (`shift` +) `ctrl` + `left`, `ctrl` + `right`, or `ctrl` + `down`.
- The effect persists through an Excel restart, or even Windows reboot.
- I already checked the `scroll lock` status.
- I'm always talking about the **left** `ctrl` key. Using the right one, in combination with an arrow key, seems to have no function (the selected cell doesn't change). I suppose this is normal, but I'm not sure as I've never tried.
- There is no other workbook open at the time.
- The workbook that is open, is a new one, and does not contain Macros. The `alt` + `F8` window shows no sub-routines that can be executed.

My hypothesis is, that I pressed the wrong keyboard shortcut, which then changed some setting that I now cannot find. I'm happy for suggestions.

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you on a laptop that has anything else function-mapped to the arrow keys?

Comment: No, at least, not to `Fn` + `up`/`down`. `Fn` + `left`/`right` is mapped to home/end. (It's a Dell Latitude E7450)

Comment: Ok - I don't know WHAT changed (as I wrote, a reboot didn't solve the problem) but as suddenly as it appeared, the problem has gone. `ctrl` + `up` seems to behave as normal again, for now.